# Automatically plot accumulated data

Tags: highcharts

I'm plotting a graph, the data in series are like below, where the time interval is one hour, the number associated to each timestamp is the number of visits of a website.

```
[
[1631138400000, 8], // 2am today
[1631142000000, 3], // 3am today
[1631145600000, 2], // 4am today
[1631149200000, 4], // 5am today
[1631152800000, 5], // 6am today
[1631156400000, 6], // 7am today
[1631160000000, 7], // 8am today
... ...
]
```

I would like to know, in Highcharts, if there is an option or API to automatically draw a graph of "accumulated" data from the data above. What I would like to plot in the graph, is 8 at 2am, 11 at 3am, 13 at 4am, 17 at 5am, etc.

Does anyone know if there is any setting to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature should be available in Highstock soon. For more information please check this issue: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/15361

For now, you can preprocess your data. Example:

```
const getCumulativeData = (data) => {
    const cumulativeData = [];

    data.forEach((dataEl, index) => {
        if (cumulativeData[index - 1]) {
            cumulativeData.push([dataEl[0], dataEl[1] + cumulativeData[index - 1][1]]);
        } else {
            cumulativeData.push(dataEl);
        }
    });

    return cumulativeData;
};
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/846cgxhL/